# User Input of Integers - Error Handling

Tags: c++, error-handling

I'm having some trouble with certain input areas of my program. There are a few parts where the user inputs a specific integer. Even if they enter the wrong one that's all fine and dandy, but I noticed if they enter anything not of integer type like 'm' then it will loop the error message repeatedly.

I have a couple functions that have integer input in them. Here's one for an example.

```
void Room::move(vector<Room>& v, int exone, int extwo, int exthree, int current)
{
    v[current].is_occupied = false;
    int room_choice;
    cout << "\nEnter room to move to: ";
    while(true)
    {
        cin >> room_choice;
        if(room_choice == exone || room_choice == extwo || room_choice == exthree)
        {
            v[room_choice].is_occupied = true;
            break;
        }
        else cout << "Incorrect entry. Try again: ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Aaarrgh!!! Why do professors keep assigning these stupid console I/O exercises?

Comment: Rolled back -- answers should not be posted in the Question box.   Instead you can accept a posted answer,  and/or post an Answer of your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `cin.good()` or `cin.fail()` to determine whether cin could successfully deal with the input value provided. You can then use `cin.clear()`, if necessary, to clear the error state before continuing processing.

Comment: Yeah, I actually tried using cin.clear() to clear out the buffer but that didn't change anything. I will try your other suggestions though.

Comment: Checking for cin.fail() and using cin.ignore() and cin.clear() patched things up. Thanks.

Comment: cin.sync() could be helpful too...it would remove all undread characters

Answer (score 12):

There is still a problem in your "solved" code.  You should check for fail() before checking the values.  (And obviously, there is the problem of eof() and IO failure as opposed to format problems).

Idiomatic reading is

```
if (cin >> choice) {
   // read succeeded
} else if (cin.bad()) {
   // IO error
} else if (cin.eof()) {
   // EOF reached (perhaps combined with a format problem)
} else {
   // format problem
}
```

Comment: But no matter how many times it is pointed out, people insist on doing it the wrong way. I've kind of given up on it :-(

Comment: Thanks AProgrammer. I'll patch that in.

Answer (score 3):

For a even simpler way, you can use `!` operator like this:

```
        if ( !(cin >> room_choice) )
        {
          cin.clear();
          cin.ignore();
          cout << "Incorrect entry. Try again: ";
        }
```