# How can I test the input data are always integer type?

Tags: c++, vector

if I want to test my input data are always integer, how can I do?
I mean I want to put the input into the vector, but I want to make sure
the inputs are integer. 
I know when I type such as "A" it will jump out the while loop. 
But I wish it can be more elegance, how can I do for this. Any suggestion?
ps: I don't want to use char to test and convert.

Here is the simple code. Thanks a lot.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
vector<int> ivec;
int num;

cout << "Please enter some integers for input or (exit) to exit" << endl;

while(cin >> num)
{
    ivec.push_back(num);
}
.....
```

Comment: [This is how you do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283302/user-input-of-integers-error-handling).

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you wish to reinvent the wheel (DIY) or if you prefer standing on the shoulders of giants.

In the latter case, I can only advise `boost::lexical_cast<T>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main() {
  std::string buffer;
  std::vector<int> vec;

  std::cout << "Please enter an integer:" << std::endl;
  while (true) {
    std::cin >> buffer;

    try {
      vec.push_back(boost::lexical_cast<int>(buffer));
      break; // exit the loop
    } catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast const&) {}

    std::cout << "Sorry, '"
              << buffer
              << "' could not be parsed as an integer, please try again."
              << std::endl;
  }

  return vec.size() == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This actually takes a little more effort than you may expect.](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html)  My advice would be to wrap this in a helper function template that takes an initial and an error message to display (although that does lead to an extra copy).

Seeing as code examples are appreciated, here are three common ways to do this.  First of all, we could choose to read as long as we have valid integers: this is the easier way.  (Required includes are assumed to be present.)

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> values;
    int i;
    while((std::cout << "Enter a number: ") && (std::cin >> i))
        values.push_back(i);
    // We've finished reading all values we could, let's work on them.
}
```

This way is short and simple, and will let the user continue by entering "exit", or in fact anything else that's not a number.  It has the advantage that you can redirect a file in and won't have to put "exit" at the end of a file (EOF will correctly terminate the loop).  However, this means that a user making an error leads to him being unable to enter any further data.

Alternatively, you can use something like this in order to read until end of stream, and then throw an exception after that.  It is not particularly neat: you end up throwing an exception as part of normal program logic, which is not generally approved of.  You could instead return a default-constructed object, or signal failure through some other means, but none of it ends up particularly neat.

```
// You could pass in output streams for prompts and errors, too.
template<typename T>
T read(std::istream& is, std::string const& prompt, std::string const& error) {
    T t;
    while ((std::cout << prompt) && !(is >> t)) {
        if (is.eof())
            throw std::runtime_error("End of stream.");
        std::cerr << error;
        is.clear();
        is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return t;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> values;
    int i = 1;
    // This way, an input of 0 will terminate the loop.  I've deviated from
    // `exit' terminating the loop -- sentinel values like that aren't very
    // flexible, so I wouldn't advise using it.
    try {
        while (i = read<int>(std::cin, "Please enter an integer: \n", "Error!\n"))
            values.push_back(i);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        // Have fun figuring out if this is end of input or something utterly unrelated.
    }
}
```

This will let you take input several times, but it's not quite as neat, and takes a lot more code.

Finally, a balance of the two uses `lexical_cast` for the conversion.  This is part of boost, but if you'd rather only use things provided by the standard library, it can be implemented as

```
template<typename OUT, typename IN>
OUT lexical_cast(IN const& in) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    OUT o;
    ss << in;
    ss >> o;
    // You may want more thorough error checking code
    if (!ss)
        throw std::runtime_error("Bad cast");
    return o;
}
```

This will translate from one type to another based on the textual, not the binary, representation.  You can now do

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> values;
    std::string input;
    while ((std::cout << "Enter an integer: ") && (std::cin >> input)) {
        if (input == "exit")
            break;
        try {
            values.push_back(lexical_cast<int>(input));
        }
        catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
            // Tell about the error, etc.
        }
    }
 }
```

In some cases, one of these is clearly better than the other; it depends on the expected method of input (will it be a user typing things in or a file redirected to standard input?) and how resistant to bad input it has to be.

Comment: While the link is relevant to the general case of input/output, I think a more specialized answer (or perhaps an excerpt focusing on the precise question here) would help a lot.

Comment: Definitely! Two remarks though (am I obnoxious...) On the second solution: to avoid the "exception in regular flow" issue, you could pass the vector in (and append in the function) and then return a boolean indicating whether to continue or not. For the `lexical_cast` implementation, the `!ss` check is insufficient. You also want to check that you have completely emptied the stream (no leftover). Otherwise I can input `1;2` and you'll accept the input (as `1`) and silently discard the `;2` part.

Comment: You could indeed pass such a vector in, but that would be an entirely different function: at the moment, the function promises to read a value no matter what (and throws if it can't satisfy that).  The problem is the function being used in a way it wasn't meant to be (to read values that might not be present).  There are indeed several extra checks that `lexical_cast` could do (such as checking if `in` was inserted correctly), but I'll leave those out for conciseness' sake.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in function atoi that converts a char array to an integer. However there are three edge cases:

- if the conversion is unsuccessful, 0 is returned so you should differentiate the two cases when 0 is returned
- if the integer value is too big INT_MAX is returned
- if the integer value is too small INT_MIN is returned

That is why I prefer to modify it a bit and handle these cases:

```
bool safe_atoi(const char* str, int *value) {
  *value = atoi(str);
  if (*value == 0) {
    return str[0] == '0' && str[1] == 0;
  }

  if (*value != INT_MAX && *value != INT_MIN) {
    return true;
  }

  if (*value == INT_MAX) {
    char buf[12];
    sprintf(buf, "%d", INT_MAX);
    return strncmp(buf, str, strlen(buf)) == 0;
  }

  if (*value == INT_MIN) {
    char buf[12];
    sprintf(buf, "%d", INT_MIN);
    return strncmp(buf, str, strlen(buf)) == 0;
  }

  return false;
}
```

And then having this function you can achieve what you wanted:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> ivec;
  int num;

  cout << "Please enter some integers for input or (exit) to exit" << endl;

  string input;

  while(cin >> input)
  {
    if (safe_atoi(input.c_str(), &num)) {
      ivec.push_back(num); 
    } else {
      // handle that case
    }
  }
```

Comment: Agreed... however using boost is not always an option. Has happened to me to work in companies where they don't want to use it for some reasons.

Comment: it's fortunate then than you can rip off the code as long as you preserve the liberal license :) One reason not to use `lexical_cast` however can be performance. It does use a `stringstream` under the hood and there are definitely faster ways to convert integers. Still, I would advise to create a "safer" alternative to your C function: in C++, it is good practice to use bounded buffers (passing an end pointer or a size... or better using directly a reference to `string` here) and you would probably return the `int` and use exceptions for errors... or at least pass by reference.

Comment: Both exceptions and references are not permitted in some of the highest ranked companies in the world and probably for a reason. The reason that I did not use c++ strings is that I wanted to make use of the built-in atoi function that handles a lot of edge cases.

Comment: Not really for *good* reasons. Exceptions are shunned in Google because they interact badly with their existing C code and their poor old C++ code (which was not written in an exception safe manner). As for pointers/references: it's a matter of style. At Google they claim it makes it easier to distinguish output parameters... but for course this is due to them using the return value to signal failure instead of exceptions. It's amusing how bad legacy code can have such a rolling ball effect on the quality of the code that is subsequently written :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try regular expressions. In C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;
    regex integer("(\\+|-)?[[:digit:]]+");
    //As long as the input is correct ask for another number
    while(true)
    {
        cout<<"Give me an integer!"<<endl;
        cin>>input;
        //Exit when the user inputs q
        if(input=="q")
            break;
        if(regex_match(input,integer))
            cout<<"integer"<<endl;
        else
        {
            cout<<"Invalid input"<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

This example can be found [here, full credit to the Author](http://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/10/12/cpp-11-regex-tutorial/). If your compiler doesn't yet support C++11 regular expressions, [boost.regex](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=boost.regex) is your next best alternative. This is a pretty heavy duty solution, however it's extensible to other sorts of inputs.

Comment: this is fine until some weirdo enters `2**32` which does not fit in your integer, and then all hell breaks loose.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You lost me there, do you mean an integer that's 32 digits long? You can always check the length of the input if this is a consideration. And anyway, that's still an integer, and it would fit into an int fine on a 64 bit platform :).

Comment: I mean an integer that does not fit in an `int` (hint: even on 64 bits platform, `int` are 4 bytes for most compilers to avoid breaking legacy code). Of course you can do length check, and this is easy, what is not is really handling all the cases. `2 147 483 648` is not fine, but `2 147 483 647` is, though they have the same length. so as soon as you hit the 10 digits length, you need to validate digit by digit. Oh, and `-2 147 483 648` IS fine (it's not symmetric)...

Comment: ... from Jamie Zawinksi: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Doh, I was thinking 2x10^32 (hence my comments about length - long day). And when I say '64 bit platform', I refer to a platform where the native word length is 64bits, I was being a bit of an arse (hence my smiley). Anyway, apart from that consideration, this is still an alternative solution to the suggested problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think in c++ your only option is to read a string.

You cold fall back to using C's scanf, which does return number of entries successfully read and will return 0, if you try to read integer, but characters have been entered.

Comment: -1, reading integers (and, in fact, anything that overloads `operator>>` in a suitable way) is possible with streams.