# Testing for an integer in c++

Tags: c++, validation, input, integer

I'm trying to write a c++ program that tests each input integer, and stops if the input is invalid.

Here is my code, without the testing part:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
    using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;

    do
    {   
        cout << "\nPlease enter an integer: ";
        cin >> i;   
        cout << endl << i << endl;

    } while(i != 0);

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

How can I test the input for validity?

Comment: `while(!(std::cin >> i)) { /* invalid input */ }` is probably what you're asking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283302/user-input-of-integers-error-handling

Comment: The loop has to be a do while, and it has to fail if the input is a float as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
   using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;

    do
    {   
        cout << "\nPlease enter an integer: ";

        while(!(cin >> i))
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "\nInput was invalid, please re-enter: ";
        }

        cout << endl << "The integer is: " << i << endl;


    } while(i != 0);

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to use `std::getline` to read a whole *line of input* into a `std::string`, and then test whether that string is a valid integer specification.

It's also possible to do this by testing the failure state of `cin`, and clearing it, but that way lies an assortment of complications that you don't want.

In order to test the string you can use a high level `std::istringstream` (just read from it and test its failure state after) or, more efficient but a little more complicated, `strtol` from the C library (the latter is what a C++ stream uses internally).

Answer (score 0):

You need to test whether a string is an integer without crashing.

You can do this with `strtol()`. It converts the string to an integer, and reports on the first character that is not a legal char for a number. No invalid characters means the entire string was an integer.

There is a good description and example of how to use it here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtol.htm