# input validation and overflow in c++

Tags: c++, validation, integer, overflow

I'm writing a code that takes a user's input and calculates a discount based on how many units the user buys. Here is my problem; I want to use input validation to make sure the number entered is between 0 and 65535 (the max range for an unsigned int) but the way I have this program set up, if the user enters a number outside of this range I'm experiencing overflow/underflow and an incorrect number is stored in the variable before it ever even hits the if/else clauses. I'm new to C++ so please be kind. What can I do to check if this number is in the correct range when the user enters it. Also, is there a way to verify that the user has not entered a character other than a number?
Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // display the instructions and inform the user of the discounts available

    cout << " This software package sells for $99. Discounts are given according to the following list: \n";
    cout << "----------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << " Quantity\t\t Discount" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << " 10 - 19\t\t 20%" << endl;
    cout << " 20 - 49\t\t 30%" << endl;
    cout << " 50 - 99\t\t 40%" << endl;
    cout << " 100 or more\t\t 50%" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\n\n";

    const double price = 99.00;

    unsigned short quantity;  // variable to hold the user's quantity. 
                              // shouldn't need more than 2 bytes for this (unsigned short)

    cout << "How many units are sold?: ";
    cin >> quantity;

    double discount; // variable to hold the amount discounted
    double total; // to hold the total sales price

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2); // set the display of numeric values

    // calculate the discounted prices

    if (quantity >= 1 && quantity <= 9) {

        total = quantity * price; // calculate the total without a discount

        cout << "There is no discount for this order \n";
        cout << quantity << " units were sold at $" << price << " a piece for a total of " << total << endl;
        cout << "\n";
    }
    else if (quantity >= 10 && quantity <= 19) {

        discount = (quantity * price) * .20; // calculate the discount
        total = (quantity * price) - discount; // calculate the total

        cout << "There is a 20% discount \n";
        cout << quantity << " units were sold at $" << price << " with a discount of 20% applied to the order. \n";
        cout << "The total cost of the sale is $" << total << endl;
        cout << "\n";
    }
    else if (quantity >= 20 && quantity <= 49) {

        discount = (quantity * price) * .30; // calculate the discount
        total = (quantity * price) - discount; // calculate the total

        cout << "There is a 30% discount \n";
        cout << quantity << " units were sold at $" << price << " with a discount of 30% applied to the order. \n";
        cout << "The total cost of the sale is $" << total << endl;
        cout << "\n";
    }
    else if (quantity >= 50 && quantity <= 99) {

        discount = (quantity * price) * .40; // calculate the discount
        total = (quantity * price) - discount; // calculate the total

        cout << "There is a 40% discount \n";
        cout << quantity << " units were sold at $" << price << " with a discount of 40% applied to the order. \n";
        cout << "The total cost of the sale is $" << total << endl;
        cout << "\n";
    }
    else if(quantity > 99 && quantity <= 65535) {

        // the maximum number allowed in a short int is 65535. I is unrealistic that someone would order more 
        // units than that so this else if clause checks to make sure the number of ordered items is below this number

        discount = (quantity * price) * .50; // calculate the discount
        total = (quantity * price) - discount; // calculate the total

        cout << "There is a 50% discount \n";
        cout << quantity << " units were sold at $" << price << " with a discount of 50% applied to the order. \n";
        cout << "The total cost of the sale is $" << total << endl;
        cout << "\n";
    }
    else {

        // the trailing else clause is used to catch any value for quantity that is 0 or below or any quantity
        // bigger than what a short int can hold. 

        cout << "You entered an invalid quantity.\n";
        cout << "Please enter a value greater than 0 or less than 65,535. \n\n";
    }




    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The final else clause is only executed when a value of 0 is entered. Here is an example of the output with a value outside the range

```
 This software package sells for $99. Discounts are given according to the following list:
----------------------------------
 Quantity                Discount
----------------------------------
 10 - 19                 20%
 20 - 49                 30%
 50 - 99                 40%
 100 or more             50%
----------------------------------


How many units are sold?: 65600
There is a 50% discount
52428 units were sold at $99.00 with a discount of 50% applied to the order.
The total cost of the sale is $2595186.00

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I have studied other languages in school. So far in this C++ class we are just getting started and haven't learned the the While loops yet so please if you can help me to find a solution without using a while loop

Comment: `// shouldn't need more than 2 bytes for this (unsigned short)` Don't try to be that clever. Just use a normal `int` for `quantity` (not `unsigned int`) and your checks will work as expected.

Comment: You can learn `while` loops yourself, they are quite simple and I'm sure your instructor would be impressed. Also, you should read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When you write the input to the unsigned short using the << operator, it is already too late! To do this the truly safe way, you would need to do some input validation on the string of characters themselves that the user has provided. You can write the input to a std::string first for that purpose.

Comment: @HelpMeI'mStupid while loops are in pretty much every modern language. If you've learned another language, you've had to have learned   about while loops.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry The point I'm trying to make is that we haven't learned while loops in this class yet so I think the instructor is trying to get us to complete the assignment without them. I knew I could change the variable type and the problem would be solved but I was trying to be efficient in my variable  usage while still performing error checking. (I was trying to use less bytes) and I thought maybe there was a better way to ensure that the data entered was within an acceptable range. Thank you everyone for your help.....I love this site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in all honesty, I don't think this is a bad question.
It just deals with error checking whatever comes out of `cin >> quantity`.

Like described here: [User Input of Integers - Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283302/user-input-of-integers-error-handling#answer-1284294), a way to handle this is to wrap the `cin >> quantity` with some error handling code like below.

```
if (cin >> quantity) {
   // read succeeded
} else if (cin.bad()) {
   // IO error
} else if (cin.eof()) {
   // EOF reached (perhaps combined with a format problem)
} else {
   // format problem
}
```

This will not take care of the integer overflows however, so a full solution would be to make `quantity` an `int` and use

```
cout << "How many units are sold?: ";
if (cin >> quantity) {
    // read succeeded

    // check for range
    if (quantity < 0 || quantity > 65535) {
        cout << "Number needs to be between 0 and 65535" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
} else if (cin.bad()) {
    // IO error
    cout << "Couldn't do a read from stdin :(" << endl;
    return -1;
} else if (cin.eof()) {
    // EOF reached (perhaps combined with a format problem)
    cout << "Stdin gave EOF :(" << endl;
    return -1;
} else {
    // format problem
    cout << "Encountered incorrect format" << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for not hating my question lol. I thought it was fair

Comment: @HelpMeI'mStupid Yes your question is not bad, but could use some improvements. nevertheless I up-voted you question, because it is clear, despite a few errors.